# Solve for $f(x)$ if $f(f(x))=6x-f(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, functional-equations

If $f: [0,\infty) \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ and

- $f(f(x))=6x-f(x)$
- $f(x)>0$ $  \forall x \in (0,\infty) $

Find f(x)

Comment: Have you tried plugging in any special values to see if you can find any simple information? One choice severely limits the number of possibilities for $f$....

Comment: @DejanGovc $f(0)=0$...

Comment: I found one but it is of negative value. :(

Comment: Looks to me like it shoulde be $f(x)=2x$ (given we need a positive solution)

Comment: Trying a simple ansatz $f(x) = ax + b$ gives a solution. It just remains to show that it is unique.

Comment: @user3006690: or -3x

Comment: @DejanGovc extremely sorry, i've now edited

Comment: Define $g(x) = f(x) - 2x$. Show that $g(f(x)) = -3g(x)$ and use this to show that $g\equiv 0$

Comment: @Hurkyl yeah f90 2x

Comment: only f(x)=2x will work, i will post my solution

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For any $x$ define a sequence, 
$$a_0=x,a_1=f(x),a_2=f(a_1) \cdots, a_{n+1}=f(a_n) $$
Putting, $a_{n}$ in equation gives, 
$$ a_{n+2}=6a_n-a_{n+1}$$ 
This is a sequence, using characteristic equation method to solve this sequence.
Since $f(x)>0$ gives, $$ a_{n} = 2^nx$$

This give $a_1=2x$ 
Checking this in functional equation, we see that it satisfies. 
And so $f(x)=2x$ is only function which satisfies the FE $\Box$

Comment: $-3x$ also works.

Comment: @KamalSaleh No, because we have the assupmtion that $ f ( x ) $ does not take negative values.

Comment: @MohsenShahriari didn't see that

Answer (score 1):

**This approach is fatally flawed.**

Here's an alternate solution via linear algebra.  Let $V=\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ denote the vector space of real functions on the real line and define $T\in V\to V$ to be the linear transformation $$(Tg)(x)=g(f(x))$$  Finally, let $p\in V$ denote the identity function, i.e. $p(x)=x$.  Then your functional equation states $$T^2p+Tp=6p$$  Rearranging, $$0=(T^2+T-6)p=(T+3)(T-2)p$$  From the general theory of linear transformations, we know that $p$ is a sum of eigenfunctions: $p(x)=q(x)+r(x)$, where \begin{gather*}
0=(T+3)q(x)=q(f(x))+3q(x) \\
0=(T-2)r(x)=r(f(x))-2r(x)
\end{gather*}

**If we are very lucky,** $p$ is in fact an eigenfunction itself: $$0=(T+3)p=f(x)+3x$$ or $$0=(T-2)p=f(x)-2x$$  We can check that each of these are solutions to conditions (1-2) and only one solves condition (3).  But I do not see how to rule out other solutions arising from linear combinations; for examples where this occurs, see the comments.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your linear algebra method, but is there some hidden assumption that you have made in your solution? If the question had been $f(f(x)) = f(x)$ instead, then using the same argument, we would get $0 = T(T-1)p$, which implies either $f(x) = 0$ or $f(x) = x$. (Then we'd eliminate $f(x) = 0$ because the range of the function is $\mathbb{R}^+$.) But $f(x) = c$ would also work for any positive constant $c$.

Comment: I have now realised, @VTand , their method relies on $T+3,T-2$ having a trivial kernel in order to deduce $(T-2)p=0$, say. That is, it assumes $T$ does not have an eigenvalue of $-3$ in the first case or $2$ in the second case. In the case $f(x)=c$ in your example, the kernel of $T$ is non-trivial, consisting of all real functions which have a root at $c$, and $T-1$ has a non trivial kernel consisting of all constant functions, therefore one cannot move from $T(T-1)p=0$ to $Tp=0\vee (T-1)p=0$.

Comment: @FShrike How about $f(f(x)) = 4x$? I believe the function $$f(x) = \begin{cases} -4x & \text{ if } x \geq 0 \\ -x & \text{ otherwise }\end{cases}$$ is a solution?

Comment: @VTand And so is $f(x)=-2x$!

Comment: @FShrike Yes, but my question is whether this solution could be found by this linear algebra method or not.

Comment: @VTand Not in the way he’s done it, no. I suspect the problem is again that $T\pm2$ has a nontrivial kernel in the case of your piecewise $f$. With all that being said, although their method isn’t surefire or particularly rigorous, it is a good and quick way to identity solutions.

Comment: @VTand: Yes, this approach is fatally flawed.  One can only conclude that $p$ is a sum of eigenfunctions, not an eigenfunction itself.  The answer has upvotes, suggesting folks found it useful, so I won't delete it (as I would otherwise).