# Is my proof that $f(x)$ where $f(f(x)) = 6x - f(x)$ for all $f:R+→R+$ is linear correct?

Tags: functions, contest-math, functional-equations

The top functional equation was assigned in a Putnam competition. To prove that this function is linear, I did the following algebra: $$f(f(x))=6x-f(x)$$ $$f(f(x)) + f(x) = 6x$$ $$\frac{f(f(x))+f(x)}{x}=6$$ Can I now say that, since this identity always results in a constant, $f(x)$ is a linear function?

Comment: You've basically just rewritten the given equation. How do you know that only linear functions satisfy it?

Comment: To elaborate on Karl's comment: Why do you think finding a constant ensures that something is linear?  Try to write down your assumption precisely.

Comment: The only way I can think of to solve this functional equation uses (college-level) linear algebra (i.e. eigenvectors).  Your bio mentions that you're a seventh grader.  Have you seen that material?  The Putnam problems _in general_ may be too hard for you right now.

Comment: @JacobManaker I don't think any linear algebra is necessarily required. [approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f%5Cleft(f%5Cleft(x%5Cright)%5Cright)%3D6x-f%5Cleft(x%5Cright)%24&p=1) yields several discussions, here and on AoPS (extracting from the functional equation a nice difference equation seems to be the method people prefer!).

Comment: @prets: I'm glad I qualified my comment with "I can think of"!  Those are cool approaches, and probably the way the OP expects to solve the problem.

Comment: The OP misses the condition $f \colon \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}^+$ from the original Putnam question.

Comment: @Karl I watched a video where the person said that since the equation (the person was working on a different functional equation) equals the constant (or constant change don't remember), than the equation.

Comment: @VTand thanks for the edit. What is the OP?

Comment: @JacobManaker I'm trying to accelerate my math skills like Terence Tao

Comment: @KamalSaleh: "OP" = "original poster"

Comment: @KamalSaleh The conclusion you can make is **not** "$f(x)$ is linear", but "$f(f(x)) + f(x)$ is linear".

Comment: @VTand Got it, thanks!

Comment: @JacobManaker thanks!

Comment: @VTand I think you meant $\frac{f(f(x)) + f(x)}{x}$

Comment: @KamalSaleh No. $f(f(x)) + f(x)$ is *linear*. $\frac{f(f(x)) + f(x)}{x}$ is *constant*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot conclude this.  From your remark in the comments, you recalled a video in which someone showed a claim like $$\require{cancel}g(x+1)-g(x)=2$$ and concluded that $g$ is linear.  This sort of claim does not generalize to $$(\text{any sort of formula using $f$ twice})=(\text{const})\Rightarrow f\text{ is linear}$$

To see why the $g$-like claim works, suppose we can ensure that $x$ is an integer like $0,1,2,\dots$.  Then $$g(3)=(g(3)-\cancel{g(2)})+(\cancel{g(2)}-\cancel{g(1)})+(\cancel{g(1)}-\cancel{g(0)})+g(0)=2+2+2+g(0)$$  In general, if $g(k)$ has $k$ summands, and so $g(k)=2k+g(0)$, which is linear.  *If $x$ is not an integer, then the claim is actually wrong: there are many solutions to the functional equation that are not linear.*

In your particular example, there is no obvious way to iterate your construction to get many values of $x$.  But note that [when the functional equation was asked here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/894347/solve-for-fx-if-ffx-6x-fx), the accepted answer did develop a similar technique to solve it.